# React won't render children, but console logs correctly

Tags: reactjs, state, react-router

I'm trying to render a list of blocks as children of my Page component. So far, I'm only seeing the console.log of blocks appearing. The blocks do not render at all, even if data are ok in the console.

What am I doing wrong

```
var Block = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var block = this.props.item;
    return (
        <div className="row" key={block.id}>
            <p>{block.name}</p>
        </div>
    );
  }
});

var Page = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      page: '',
      blocks: [],
      newBlockValue: ''
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get("/pages/"+this.props.page+".json", function (result) {
        this.setState({
            page: result.page,
            blocks: result.blocks
        });
    }.bind(this));
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    var page = this.state.page;
    return (
        <div className="row">
            {this.state.blocks.forEach(function(block){
                console.log(block);
                <Block key={block.id} item={block} />
            })}
            <form id="add_new_block">
                <input type="text" id="new_block" value={this.state.newBlockValue} onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="off"/>
                <input type="submit" value='Save' onClick={this.createBlock}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: Not at all, just the objects like : Object { id: 8, name: "foo" }

Comment: Is your form appearing?

Comment: Yes, and it's also working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `map` instead of `forEach`.

Calling `forEach` on an array returns `undefined`. You want to give as child to your `Page` element an array of `Block` elements, not `undefined`.

Also you should `return` your `Block` element, otherwise you'll end up with an array of `undefined`:

```
this.state.blocks.map(function(block){
    return <Block key={block.id} item={block} />
})
```

Comment: Right, I changed my forEach into map, it keeps making logs but still won't render anything

Comment: @Hipjea I've edited my answer with an additional precision

Comment: just to add a bit to the above: this is in part due to how JSX works; when you use `forEach`, you're essentially passing `react.createElement(someParentElement, anyProps, undefined);`. It expects `...children` as the last parameter, an array of child elements to create. So, you need map to return an array it can use :)